# Google analytics with meta http-equiv="REFRESH" redirection

Tags: redirect, google-analytics

Is it possible to apply google analytics to pages that use the `<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url={url}">` redirect method?

I'm assuming that the redirection on this type of page would happen before the js has a chance to run, and so analytics would not work on it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you want to track these pages, you need to fire the Google Analytics tracking first and next only, redirect.

I would recommend:

- using the ga.js traditional syntax over the async syntax
- wait something like 150ms after the tracking has been called, before redirecting (with setTimeout() , in Javascript instead of using  meta tag)

Use Google Chrome's [Google Analytics debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) extension for example to check how it goes

Comment: So you're saying the ga.js instead of async still necessitates a wait? 150ms is an arbitrary number, what's the point?

Comment: Yes, ga.js traditional http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingOverview.html AND a wait to let the browser send the request before replacing the current page.
150 ms is arbitrary I admit (depends on your audience typical connectivity) but should work good enough for 95% of users.
For the moment there is no other mean to do this with 100% reliability.